# model's information keep in sync with external source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, laravel, design-patterns

I will develop a new app (Maybe using Laravel or Rails). The point is that we will have our database with let's say user table so at application level, we will have a User model. When User model change, we will send a notification to another external source instantly. In the future the app must allow switch the external source.

I think that a good option is create a UserService ([Service layer design patter](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html)) class to wrap the logic (keeping data in sync) and then all controllers will use it.

What do you think about it's the best way to do it?

Comment: Question is pretty confusing. You've hardly explained why you'd persist at an external source. Let alone that you should be building an API client if this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only have experience with Laravel so I'll be speaking for Laravel.

Laravel provides [pretty much this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events) - out of the box. It provides events for Model methods, such as saving, saved, created, creating... So it's extremely easy to set up service-level notifications on any of those events. It's also really easy to define your own events, if you need more specific triggers.

However, since you're doing this on application level, you will **need to make sure** everything is saved through your application's models. Say, if someone was to edit some data directly through SQL, it would bypass the events. So you need to make sure that everything (for example a mobile app connected to your service) is saved through your application.

Another option would be to use some database that provides that functionality (PostgreSQL out of free ones). But judging by "In the future the app must allow switch the external source." it's exactly what you're trying to avoid.